# How to best encapsulate Google JS API on AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, google-api-client

I want to use the [Google JS API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/) on my AngularJS web app. As I'm a newbie using Angular I'm a bit confused on how to encapsulate the gAPI calls. Basically I want to authenticate users and call some Google APIs (eg: spreadsheets, calendar, email, etc).

Considering a basic AngularJS app structure (main module, controllers, services, providers, etc), I decided to create a provider in order to encapsulate the [Google oAuth authentication flow](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication). And then I created some services to make the services' API call (calendar, docs, etc). Here I stated to get lost... :-\

Some questions:

1. How can I control (verify if the user is already authenticated) the access to my views? In each service or view controller? Or maybe on `$routeProvider` config?
2. In terms of Angular service/provider design... Is better to expose all the gAPI functionality I want to use in a Angular Service/Provider or simply access the `gapi` object directly in each angular controller/service?

Comment: Hi @KevinLe
thanks for your quick reply! I'll take a look on this repo. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe consider using a library like https://github.com/maximepvrt/angular-google-gapi. These types of questions are hard to answer without knowing the scope of your application.

In general, I'd consider how much of the GAPI you are using and how much abstraction of the GAPI you will need. If you are doing fairly light weight things, then it may be fine to call the GAPI directly.

If you think you will be reusing the GAPI throughout the application, consider using the linked library or even wrapping the GAPI with your own services and providers.